# Eclipse builds too slow

Tags: c, windows, eclipse, performance

I have just installed eclipse 4.14 on windows for my C course. But building even 3 lines of code takes 30 seconds when it barely takes a second on all of my friends' computers. There were no errors during/after the installation.

I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling, opening a new workspace, increasing the memory on .ini file and turning of auto build. None of them worked. Only switching from build externally to internally reduced the building time down to 10 seconds but it is still not ideal.

edit- I installed cygwin as the compiler and eclipse is on the c drive.I also added eclipse to the exclusion list of the antivirus.

What else can I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: probably antivirus.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is fine, however you might like to take the [tour] and read "[ask]", just FYI. -- How long does it take to build a program *outside* of Eclipse? I mean, write the source with any editor, Eclipse or else, and compile and link it in a "`cmd` window". This is BTW a good exercise to get a grip on the compiler. -- Where (on what drive) did you install Eclipse, and where did you install the compiler? Which compiler is it?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion,I will check it out. Compiling on cmd takes 5-6 seconds on average. Edited the question for other details. Eclipse is under c: .

Comment: Such long times should be watchable with a process explorer (delivered with Windows or ProcessExplorer). You might be able to see whether GCC is delaying or not. -- Another idea: once I heard about `wtrace`, a tool analoguous to `strace` but for Windows. It logs system API calls to find some hints. Possibly there are other methods, like using ProcessMonitor, but I never needed to use them.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try them and see if I can find anything.